Using illustrations and comics in dissertations
It's common to use quotes related to the context in the first page of each parts in PhD dissertations and books. Is it also acceptable to use some illustration instead, similar to dummies book series?

Ask your advisor.

What is acceptable is up to your advisor and your institution. Some things are probably more likely to be acceptable than others. Be aware of potential copyright issues (and citations) of course.
Whether it is "acceptable" to readers, is a different, and unanswerable in general, question. Relevance probably matters. A certain amount of humor is probably ok with many as long as it isn't overdone or too obscure.

Will you publish your dissertation some day?  When you do, comics and illustrations may need to be licensed; perhaps there would be a fee for them.
